# Wrong decoding with utf_7

Tags: python, codec, utf

I use the following python code to decode a "text" file:

```
import codecs, os, sys
fd = open("c:/a.txt", 'rb')
rb = fd.read()
s = codecs.decode(rb, 'utf_7')
print(s)
```

and get following errors on running:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf7' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: unexpected special character
```

But the "text" file can be decoded by the iconv utility, shown as follows:

```
$iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-7 a.txt
01 +ANYA2AC5AOkAywDVAMEAqw
```

So what is wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue19279). Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.4

Comment: And the same error on python 2.7

Comment: Apply the patch & retry ? And some posts suggest that instead of using `codecs`, `imapclient` also provides utf7 decode function.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of the `iconv` that you gave is:

```
s = rb.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-7')
```

You were missing a step.